# Improve Delete Performance by Running Select Query First

Tags: mysql

Does doing a select query on the rows to be deleted help running a delete query performance? For example, if I do this:

`select * from t1 where test_id = x   -- will look for 100,000 rows`

then run this:

`delete from t1 where test_id = x`

I would think it helps because wouldn't the select query put the data into the InnoDB buffer pool? I haven't tested it because I'm not sure how to properly test it.

Comment: Even if running the select could put all the data into the buffer pool, the total time of running the select and the delete cannot be less than running the delete alone.

Comment: But would it help improve the overall timing of the delete query since the data is already in the Innodb buffer pool?

Comment: How to test: Look at the clock. Run the command. Look at the clock again. How much time has passed? (you can also measure time in code)

Comment: hmm... I guess I can just stop MySQL, run the select + delete... then stop MySQL again, then run the delete only

Comment: You don't need to stop MySQL. Just measure the time before you run the query, and measure the time again after it completes. Measure again before the select+delete queries, and measure again after these two complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer: **NO**

If it appears to be faster, it is because of a query cache. As someone said before, you are basically running the same query twice, and the second time is pulling the results from the cache.

To optimize that **delete**, you need an **index** for the **test_id** column.

Comment: Not the "query cache", the "buffer_pool".

Answer (score 1):

In both cases the data needs to be located and loaded off disk. Whether you do that by running a `SELECT` first or not is irrelevant.

You're just doubling the amount of times the table needs to be locked when running twice the amount of queries against it, in this case, ergo twice the work.

Furthermore, it'll almost always be slower to run two queries here, the first being a `SELECT`, for a multitude of reasons. One reason being is `SELECT *` means you're telling it to load all columns off disk. The wider the table and the larger the size of the data types of those columns (and data that's stored in them), the longer it's going to take for the `SELECT` query to run. For the `DELETE` query alone, it does not have this same amount of work.